# there may be more to the world than can be understood by physical science

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Physical science has progressed by leaving the mind out of what it
>   tries to explain, but **there may be more to the world than can be
>   understood by physical science**.

[What does it all mean? Thomas Nagel]

I think the **bold sentence** means "there are more things in the world that can't be understood by physical science. Is it right?

Many thanks!

Comment: There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio / than are dreamt of in your philosophy...

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then that is almost what he means but not quite. He is saying that, while the world contains some things that can be understood by physical science, the world may also contain more things than that.

"There is more to X than Y" in general means that while Y is a part of X, it is not the entirety of X; there is more constituting X than just Y.